# Masstransit and RabbitMQ to Console Application (use Asp.net Core Web API)

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, console-application, masstransit, producer-consumer

I created a Solution with ASP.NET Core WEB API project, some class libraries (Domain, DI and ect), and a console application.
A console application that I use as a RabbitMQ Consumer with Masstransit library   it should take messages from RabbitMQ (I have Producer project and it sends for RabbitMQ messages without problems)

My ConsoleApplication:
like this Program.cs:

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();

                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    var connectionString = new Uri("RabbitMQ_URL");
                    cfg.Host(connectionString);

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
            services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);


            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
}
```

With Worker.cs:

```
  public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    readonly IBus _bus;

    public Worker(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { Uri = new 
            Uri("RabbitMQ_URL"), DispatchConsumersAsync = true };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "MessageQueue",
                 durable: true,
                 exclusive: false,
                 autoDelete: false,
                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                var @event = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event> 
                    (message);

                await _bus.Publish(new Event { DataJson = @event });

                await Task.Yield(); 
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "MessageQueue",
                                 autoAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);
            
            _logger.LogInformation("Received Text: {Text}", context.Message.DataJson);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

MessageConsumer.cs:

```
 public class MessageConsumer :
    IConsumer<Event>
{
    readonly ILogger<MessageConsumer> _logger;

    public MessageConsumer(ILogger<MessageConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Event> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInInformation("Recieved Text: {Text}, 
          context.Message.DataJson");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
    }
```

And my Event.cs:

```
 public class Event
{
    public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
    public string DataJson { get; set; }
}

public enum ServiceType
{
    ComplareSitter
}
```

Please help me
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might start with a clean and simple worker service using one of the MassTransit templates, just to verify your setup/configuration. There is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYKq61-DFBQ&feature=youtu.be) available showing how to setup and use the templates.

But an obvious question, **why on earth** are you connecting to RabbitMQ and creating a basic consumer inside the `Consume` method? The message has already been deserialized as your `Event` type and is ready to be used. There is absolutely no need to use any part of the RabbitMQ Client library in your application when using MassTransit.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! In Woker class (ExecuteAsync method) i need configure my RabbitMQ connection. But, in program.cs i need it too. How can i configure once? Or its needed ? I have corrected the question and source code

Comment: I don't think you need anything in the `Worker` class, at all. There isn't any reason to connect to RabbitMQ yourself, MassTransit does it.